# them & color for bus station and bus route information

Tags: android, google-chrome, themes

I want a theme like this photo I design my Android application
What phrase in Google search that such themes that give it to me ?
My application is about the bus station and bus route,What color should I use?!
[photo](http://i60.tinypic.com/efl4br.png)